# Problems with encoding of .bbl file created by BibTeX for LuaLaTeX

Tags: bibtex, luatex, unicode, input-encodings, jabref

I am trying to use BibTeX and LuaLaTeX. However, I get the error message

> File: project.bbl 
> String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence

for several bibliography entries that contain characters such as ä, é, á etc. The encoding of the .bbl file is set to ISO-8859-1, which should of course be UTF-8. Every time I recompile, the encoding will be reset to ISO-8859-1. How to I resolve this problem?

I am using TeXstudio for editing the TeX files and JabRef to edit the bibliography.

Comment: You write, "Every time I recompile, the encoding [of the bib file] will be reset to ISO-8859-1." Why? *What* exactly are you recompiling? Do you use some software tool that recreates the bib file?

Comment: @Mico Everytime the bibliography is recompiled. The .bbl file is created by BibTeX from the .bib file.

Comment: BibTeX can only deal with US-ASCII characters. *Normally* it just passes non-ASCII characters through as is (and may fail to sort them correctly etc.), but it is not entirely inconcievable that it may mangle some non-ASCII chars in certain situations. Check that your `.bib` file is ASCII only. (If the `.bib` file contains non-ASCII chars, things *might* work if everything is encoded in UTF-8, but there is no guarantee.)

Comment: Have you ensured that JabRef sets the input encoding of the bib file to utf8?

Comment: @Mico Yes, that is set correctly.